# Twilio Received an error from MediaStream

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to integrate Twilio in my Laravel application so far I was doing great generated the access token, created the device but when I run `device.connect(param)` it give me this error in the console.

> twilio.min.js:99 Received an error from MediaStream: Error code: 31000

I have searched the twilio documentation for this error but couldn't resolve it can anyone please help me out with this. Here's my code.

**JS**

```
function callCustomer(phoneNumber) {
    alert(phoneNumber);
    $.get("/token", {forPage: window.location.pathname}, function (data) {
        const device = new Twilio.Device();
        var params = {"phoneNumber": phoneNumber};
        device.setup(data);
        device.connect(params);
    });
}
```

Here is the picture of complete console error.

[image]

According to the error it says something about stable connection and I do have stable connection which works perfectly fine when I was working on other projects. Any hint or code will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `device.connect` inside the ready event like this.

```
device.on('ready', function(device){
  device.connect(params);
});
```

Hope this will help someone else in future.